# Adding white space in XML file tag

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I have a requirement where i need to extract Powerpoint text. Every thing is working fine as perl script is able to read `<a:t></a:t>` tag. but it is not able to give a white space after text. Below is the detail explaination:
file.xml

```
<a:t>Stack</a:t>
<a:t>Overflow</a:t>
```

The output it is printing is **StackOverflow**. What i want is **Stack Overflow**

Below is the code what i am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES );
use XML::Twig;
my @text;

my $file = "test_server-1.pptx";
my $zip  = Archive::Zip->new();
$zip->read($file) == AZ_OK or die "Unable to open Office file\n";
my @slides = $zip->membersMatching("ppt/slides/slide.+\.xml");

#print @slides;
for my $i ( 1 .. scalar @slides ) {    # to sort them.
    my $content = $zip->contents("ppt/slides/slide${i}.xml");

    my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
        keep_encoding => 1,
        twig_handlers => { 'a:t' => \&topicref_processing, },
    );
    $twig->parse($content);
}

sub topicref_processing {
    my ( $twig, $ppttext ) = @_;
    print $ppttext->text();
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want artificial whitespace, you'll simple needed to add it:

```
sub topicref_processing {
    my($twig, $ppttext) = @_;   
    print $ppttext->text(), " ";
}
```